# vuejs3 I18n and composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, i18next

I'm right now doing a frontend interface in vueJS, and i'm currently working with vuejs 3 and i18n. The implementation of i18n works quite fine the normal way but when I want to use it with the composition API starts the problems.

So what I did. My main.js looks like this:

```js
const i18n = createI18n({
    messages: {
        en: en,
        fr: fr
    },
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    locale: localStorage.Language || navigator.language.split('-')[0] || 'en',
})
const app = createApp(App)


app.use(router)
app.use(i18n)

app.mount('#app')
```

I saw in [the documentation](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#basic-usage) to use composition API I have to add legacy:false so I did it. Then my $t doesn't work anymore. I go firther in the documentation and arrive at the point I'm lost with. The documentation saiys to use this:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const { t } = VueI18n.useI18n() // call `useI18n`, and spread `t` from  `useI18n` returning
    return { t } // return render context that included `t`
  }
})
```

My problem is that my createApp is already used like this:

```js
const app = createApp(App)
```

which is the default implementation by Vuejs.
I tried to modify it adding the setup after App, before, removing App nothing works and I think I do more and more stupid things.

Does anyone has an idea how to make i18n works with the composition API? The final objective is basically in a component switchLanguage made with composition API to have access to $i18n (to get some informations and manage my language switch)

Thanks in advance for the help you can provide.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/blob/master/example/vue/src/vue-i18next.js

Comment: Not really, not sure to fully understand

Comment: ahh you’re using VueI18n, your i18next tag confused me

Comment: is it not the good approach?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know VueI18n

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already instantiated `i18n` on your app, in `main.js`. That's the important bit.

The example presented in docs doesn't necessarily have to be done on the instance defined inside `createApp`. It works in any component, as long as you have instantiated i18n on `main.(js|ts)`

This will work in any component (wherever you need `t`):

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n();
    // you can now use t('some.text.to.be.translated')
    // t('some.text.to.be.pluralized', { n: 1 }, 1);

    return {
      // expose `t` to <template>:
      t, 
    }
  },
  // if you want it inside any method, computed or hook
  // in case you still use Options API
  computed() {
    someTranslatedText() {
      return useI18n().t('translate.me');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    methodNeedingTranslation() {
      const { t } = useI18n();
      // do stuff with `t`
    }
  }
})
```

Side note: All `$tc` ([pluralization](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#pluralization)) functionality has been moved to `t`.

If you're upgrading an existing app and you don't want to go through templates and replace all instances of `$t` and `$tc` with `t`:

```
setup: () => ({ 
  $t: useI18n().t
  $tc: useI18n().t 
})
```

---

To make `$t` and `$tc` available in any component's `<template>`, without having to import + expose them in `<script>` (or `<script setup>`):

```js
import App from './App.vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$t = useI18n().t
```

- If you still need them in `<script>`, import from `'vue-i18n'`, as shown above.
- `$tc` is no longer used in Vue3. If your templates are coming from Vue2, it would be best to replace all `$tc`'s with `$t`. Or you could assign `useI18n().t` to both, if you don't want to touch the templates:

```js
Object.assign(app.config.globalProperties, {
  $t: useI18n().t,
  $tc: useI18n().t
})
```

Comment: Hi @tao Thaks for this answer. The way you present it on the first code is not using compostion API right?

Comment: It actually is. Composition API means, basically, having a `setup()` function and rewriting all the Options API (computed, methods, hooks) inside this `setup` function). However, you should be aware Composition API is compatible with Options API. They can be used both in the same component, at the same time. So you can have `setup()` and `computed` or `methods` inside a `defineComponent()`. It was made like this so that you don't have to rewrite the entire component in Composition API. You can move things into `setup` one by one and still test if it all works, before focusing next method.

Comment: @Tartempion, Are you using `<script setup>`? Is that what you're calling Composition API?

Comment: Oh ok so first I didn't know we can use both. Yeah I was talking about the <script setup> sorry I just start with composition API I don't explain it well. So I guess I can not use setup() inside the script setup right?

Comment: The thing is I use Json files for my translations which works well for now. I don't know if it is important. And I don't want to declare i18n again in every component. For that I guess I can just make it in my App.vue

Comment: @Tartermpion, Composition API is all about importing `useStuff()` functions wherever you need "stuff" and about not having globals. If you wanted it, you can declare globals, to be available throughout your app, but, in general, it's regarded as an anti-pattern in Vue 3. Think about it, you even import `computed`, `ref`, `watch` and other basic Vue stuff in each of the components, where you need them. They could be globals, but they're not. That's the principle: you expose to each template the least possible amount of variables it needs to perform.

Comment: Ok I guess I'm not fully ready for composition API yet. I will just continue learning and come back to it later. Thanks for all your answers

Comment: I'm using Vue3, Typescript, `<script setup>` and having to add `import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'; const { t } = useI18n();` into each SFC that uses `t()`. Is that right? any easy way of make 't' work globally?

Comment: @Roddy, I completed the answer with how to make `$t` (and `$tc`) available in templates without having to import them in every component.